# Como envio un file por ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentado enviar un fichero a traves de ajax pero me devuelve el siguiente error en el php, e intentado enviar en el data del jquery el adjunto att pero claro me da error porque "$_FILES['att_01']['name'];" no esta definido. no se como enviarlo por ajax el adjunto. a ver si me podeis ayudar.

**Notice**:  Undefined index: att_01 in **index.php** on line 5

### Adjunto codigo html

```html
<form data-parsley-validate="true" id="contactForm" method="post" name="datosForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="javascript:;">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre *</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="80" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="name" id="name" minlength="3" required data-msg="Inserta un Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>Adjunto 1</strong></label>
    <div id="att_01_report"></div>
    <div id="att_01_input">
      <input id="att_01" name="att_01" class="file" type="file" />
      <strong>* Formatos aceptados:</strong><br /> <em>jpg, png, gif, bmp, pdf, doc, docx</em>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>Adjunto 2</strong></label>
    <div id="att_02_report"></div>
    <div id="att_02_input">
      <input id="att_02" name="att_02" class="file" type="file" />
      <strong>* Formatos aceptados:</strong><br /> <em>jpg, png, gif, bmp, pdf, doc, docx</em>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" id="contact_submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

### Adjunto codigo jquery

```html
 $("#contact_submit").on("click", function(){

   name = $("#contactForm #name").val(),

   $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: "./save",
    data: {
     "name": name
    }
   }).done(function( info ){
    var json_info = JSON.parse(info);
    view_msg(json_info);
      $("#modalForm").modal("toggle");
      table.ajax.reload();
     });
   }
 });
```

Solucion

Lo he resuelto haciendo estos cambios en el jquery

```html
   e.preventDefault();
   var packetData = new FormData();
   packetData.append("att_01", $("#att_01")[0].files[0]);
   packetData.append("att_02", $("#att_02")[0].files[0]);
      
    url: "./save",
    contentType: false,
    data: packetData,
    processData: false,
    cache: false
```

Comment: Resuelto. adjunto la solucion

Comment: Por favor por la solución *como respuesta* para que los demás sepan. Hasta puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Solucion

Lo he resuelto haciendo estos cambios en el jquery

```html
$("#contact_submit").on("click", function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
   var packetData = new FormData();
   packetData.append("att_01", $("#att_01")[0].files[0]);
   packetData.append("att_02", $("#att_02")[0].files[0]);
      
   $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: "./save",
    contentType: false,
    data: packetData,
    processData: false,
    cache: false
   }).done(function( info ){
    var json_info = JSON.parse(info);
    view_msg(json_info);
      $("#modalForm").modal("toggle");
      table.ajax.reload();
     });
   }
 });
```